# using timer in background worker in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am develping an app which load some url, parse them, keep them into sqlite db and the UI will read the saved data and show them in controls. This progress should be done in almost an infinit loop. For having fast response i plan to read the data from db in main thread and have an other thread (background worker) to load the data and insert it into db. Is it logical and possible to run read and write process in dispatchertimer, one timer in main thread and the other inside the background worker? and how? Or does anyone have better idea?

```
main thread:
    DispatcherTimer _Timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
                _Timer1.Interval = _Interval;
                _Timer1.Tick += _Timer1_Tick;
    void _Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               // read data from db and show in controls
             }

secondary thread:
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        DispatcherTimer _Timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
                _Timer2.Interval = _Interval;
                _Timer2.Tick += _Timer2_Tick;


    }
    void _Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               // write data into db
             }
    }
```

Comment: do you have a sample of your work ? just for know correctly the problem.

Comment: @Doc Roms: i have edit the question, now you may get idea what i am talking about. Is that sound logical? is there any better way?

Comment: I would like to run the read and write in db frequently and be able to stop the timer or change in interval after first run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're planning to do wont work.

Both your `_Timer1_Tick` and `_Timer2_Tick` will run in the UI thread. If you perform some long-running operations there, it'll hang the UI.

I don't get it, why do you need timers at all? Using timers for anything else but measuring time intervals is rarely a good strategy. You could e.g. run your update process in the infinite loop in background, as soon as it put new data in the DB you call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (passing any data you want) to notify your UI thread it should update itself with the newly available data.

And by the way, for the tasks like "send HTTP request, wait response, parse, store, repeat", the new async/await feature is a natural choice. For WP7 the functionality is available as "Async CTP" redistributable package for Visual Studio 2010, for WP8 it's already integrated into the framework. There're some compatibility issues between the 2, though.

Answer (score 1):

> load some url, parse them, keep them into sqlite db and the UI will read the saved data and show them in controls

Please don't do that. Don't create your own thread management system, just don't. I'm not saying it won't work, but it'll most likely backfire in the most horrendous and inexplicable ways. Like for example using a DisptacherTImer completely exploding in your face since it runs on the UI thread. If you really want to use threading considering [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx) or [Task.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051.aspx) to start fire-and-forget actions.

Your workflow is also just strange, I don't get why you need to write data you already have to a DB, then read it back and only then use it. Won't it make more sense to use the deserialized data to sequentially write it to the DB and present it to the UI? Instead of doing the needless loop of involving Disk I/O considering you already have the data?

Have you considered using Messaging in your app? It's a pretty well known MVVM pattern implemented both in MVVM Light as the [Messenger](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/mvvm-light-whats-messenger) class and in PRISM as the [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx). It seems to me that your system has a Message for "new data available from service" and that message has two subscribers: writing to a DB and updating the UI.

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous. By saying UI read the saved data i meant the data i have just save after parsing. So you just imagine i have write and read process which the reading is in UI thread and the write is in secondary thread.